# Freeze mobilenet_v2 (freeze_graph.py)

Tags: tensorflow

I trained mobilenet_V2 using slim's [train_image_classifier](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/train_image_classifier.py). My command was:

```
python3 ~/models/research/slim/train_image_classifier.py \
--model_name="mobilenet_v2" \
--learning_rate=0.045 * 2 \
--preprocessing_name="inception_v2" \
--label_smoothing=0.1 \
--moving_average_decay=0.9999 \
--batch_size=16 \
--num_clones=2 \
--learning_rate_decay_factor=0.98 \
--num_epochs_per_decay=2.5 / 2 \
--train_dir=[...]/tensorflow_logs/mobilenet_v2 \
--dataset_dir=[...]/imagenet_data \
--dataset_name='imagenet' \
--train_image_size=229
```

It created the following files in mobilenet_v2/ (not the full list):

```
checkpoint
graph.pbtxt
[...]
model.ckpt-697555.data-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt-697555.index
model.ckpt-697555.meta
```

I am able to do inference using my checkpoint.

I am now struggling to convert my checkpoint variables to Const ops with freeze graph. When I try:

```
python3 -m tensorflow.python.tools.freeze_graph \
  --input_graph [...]/tensorflow_logs/mobilenet_v2/graph.pbtxt \
  --input_checkpoint [...]/tensorflow_logs/mobilenet_v2/model.ckpt-697555 \
  --input_binary false \
  --output_graph /mnt/sda1/tensorflow_logs/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2_frozen.pb \
  --output_node_names MobilenetV2/Predictions/Reshape_1
```

I get: `AssertionError: MobilenetV2/Predictions/Reshape_1 is not in graph` 
However the output of: `[print(n.name) for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]` contains:

```
MobilenetV2/Logits/Squeeze
MobilenetV2/Logits/output
MobilenetV2/Predictions/Reshape/shape
MobilenetV2/Predictions/Reshape
MobilenetV2/Predictions/Softmax
MobilenetV2/Predictions/Shape
MobilenetV2/Predictions/Reshape_1
```

Hence my confusion.

Last time I was able to freeze my graph I used the `input_saved_model_dir` option to load a saved model [I believe those are now the preferred method ?] instead of input_graph and input_checkpoint. Unfortunately the `train_image_classifier.py` script doesn't create one, only the checkpoints.

Any ideas/ comments appreciated!

Comment: Why do you give both input_graph as well as input_binary false. Try to omit both arguments. Example: freeze_graph --input_graph mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_quant_eval.pbtxt \
--input_checkpoint mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_quant.ckpt \
--output_graph foo_frozen.pb \
--output_node_names=MobilenetV2/Predictions/Reshape_1